# Javascript — two instances of the same elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to write a loan calculator in Javascript.

You can have a look here:  http://codepen.io/saltcod/pen/vHrfc

Things are working nicely, except when I click try and add a second instance of the calculator to the page (via the + button). When I do that, the two calculators don't work independently.

How can I make all of the calculators on a page act independently?

Thanks for anyone able to point me in the right direction.

Terry

Comment: When you're adding a new calculator you're cloning an existing one, which will clone ID etc. ID's must be unique on the page. If they're not not you'll have trouble. I note also that your selectors are using classe rather than IDs. Even though classes need not be unique, your selectors might pick up more than you expect.

Comment: On a separate note your loan calculations aren't correct. Check out Oak Road Systems (http://oakroadsystems.com/math/loan.htm) for an explanation of the financial maths formulas. And perhaps look at Formula.js (http://stoic.com/formula/) which is an open source JavaScript library that implements these standard loan formulas (matching Excel's results very closely).

Comment: You're right about the calculations. I knew something wasn't adding up! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first, don't use `id` attributes unless they are used to identify the same element every time. since you clone the same element, and since keyup can happen on whichever of these elements, you can use `class` instead.

another thing is, that you only attach a keyup handler for elements in the original calculator. once you clone it then the new calculator has no handler attached. instead you can use a delegate

`$(document).on("keyup", selectors, handler)`

where in the handler function, you can add

`group = $(this).parents(".loan.group")`

and all selectors should have `group` as a scope, for example:

`... years = +$('.years',group).val(),` instead of `... years = +$('.years').val(),`

[here is an improved version of your calculator, I hope this helps](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/tDauw)

Comment: Thanks so much. I should have known not to use ids!  Thank you!